# How to serialize everything but the checkbox elements in jQuery.serialize()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

is there a way to serialize all form elements using serialize() function except the checkboxes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs:

> The .serialize() method can act on a
>   jQuery object that has selected
>   individual form elements, such as
>   `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`.

You could do this:

```
var s = $('#post-form').find('input, textarea, select')
                       .not(':checkbox')
                       .serialize()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/), [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selectors:

```
var serialized = $(":input:not(:checkbox)").serialize();
```

Comment: Does not consider form elements other than `<input>`

Comment: @Simeon, the `:input` selector *does* match `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` elements. Look at the first link in my answer: `the :input selector basically selects all form controls`.

Comment: Both your and Simeons code helped me, though I liked his style better, and he was first so I marked his answer as correct. Thx both for your help.

Comment: @Frederic: really? Cause I see that he answered 55mins ago, and you 1h ago.. Ok, nevermind, you have a lot of points so ;)

Comment: @Frédéric: True, I missed the colon. Removing my -1